# Ansible couldn't locate rsync even though rsync installed in the server

Tags: ansible, rsync, ansible-2.x

I tried executing a synchronize push task in ansible as seen below:

```
- name: Transfer package from server to target server
  synchronize:
     src: "{{ item }}"
     dest: "{{ item }}"
     mode: push
   with_items:
     - "/opt/screener/{{PACKAGE_NAME}}"
```

But it throws an error saying that it failed to find rsync executable

> Failed to find required executable "rsync" in paths:
> /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

But when I check in the servers, I am able to find that the rsync is installed and working fine as seen below:

```
[server ~]$ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes, prealloc

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
[server ~]$ whereis rsync
rsync: /usr/bin/rsync /usr/share/man/man1/rsync.1.gz
```

Should I have to manually map the path to rsync? How should I do it? Or what else should be done?

Comment: Dou you have rsync installed on _both_ server and control host? Your question includes one server only.

Comment: It is installed in all 3 servers. I get the same version number and same path in all 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` should also be installed on the ansible node (where you're running your playbooks)

Comment: rsync is installed in both the source server and destination server, and in ansible node because when I run the command suggested in [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/886464/ansible-error-failed-to-find-required-executable-rsync-in-paths-usr-local-sbi), it says that rsync is already installed in the server.

Comment: is it accessible withe same user you're running ansible with (locally) and with the user ansible connects with (distant) ?